# Document management system with version control and access rights control in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

I need to create document management system and for that I have a set of requirements (not well fleshed out) that cover a system to manage documents (word docs, designs, etc.) for both internal and external use. Basically what we need is a system that allows users to have multiple versions of docs online, publish at will and keep working on new revs. We also need to have inside and outside facing interfaces with access control and permissions enforcement (this might be best covered with separate sites and doc pushes to the outside facing interface).

I looked at [Document module](https://www.drupal.org/project/document), but i think it is still under development.

So, the question is: Is there a distribution or a set of modules already in place that closely approximates this set of requirements, or am I looking a tough rocky climb to get where we need to be?

Comment: I did something similar by combining organic groups, views and by carfully setting the drupal private files directory to avoid data leaks. My advice is not to use drupal revisions for revisions but to emulate this with views